# Subfields and Isomorphisms.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $E$ and $F$ be subfields of a finite field $K$.
>
> Show that if $E$ is isomorphic to $F$, then $E=F$.

I am considering the subfield property and isomorphisim, is that ok?

Comment: You are expected (my educated guess) to heavily use the fact that $K$ is finite.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- Show that $|E|=|F|$. Call this number $q$.
- Consider the set of solutions of $x^q=x$ in the field $K$.

Answer (score 1):

Use structure theory of finite fields. A finite field $K = K_{p^n}$ is of order $p^n$, then $E\cong F$ are of order $p^k$ where $k\le n$. We know $E,F$ are both splitting field of $f(x) = x^{p^k}-1$ over $Z_p\subset K$. But there is only one such splitting field inside $K$.